# JavaScript function doesn't return correct value

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a function in which I'd like to check which useragent is currently being used.
The following code is just a prototype and it returns whatever value it reads first - in this case `IE`.

```
detectDevice = function () {
    var userAgent = {
        detect: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent;
        },
        detectBrowser: function () {
            var browser = userAgent.detect();
            var currentBrowser;
            return currentBrowser = browser.indexOf('IE') ? "Internet Explore" : browser.indexOf('Mozilla') ? "FireFox" : "UserAgent not recognized!";
        },
        version: function (identifier) {
        }
    };

    alert(userAgent.detectBrowser());
}
```

I can't tell what's wrong. Maybe you guys can see it and tell me where I made a wrong turn.

Comment: Have you already tried to use `$.browser` instead? or it's not suitable for your purposes?

Comment: What is the problem with the code above? Also, you might be interested in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ - you could look at the jQuery source code to see how they do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1` if no match is found. If a match is found, the returned value is the character index of the found substring.

To check whether a substring exists, you should use:

```
browser.indexOf('IE') != -1
// If a match is found, a non-negative index is returned. So, this also works:
//..... indexOf('IE') > -1
// .... indexOf('IE') >= 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return (browser.indexOf('IE') > -1)
           ? "Internet Explorer" 
           : (browser.indexOf('Mozilla') > -1)
                ? "FireFox" 
                : "UserAgent not recognized!";
```

Comment: I'm not going to upvote this answer, since despite being correct, it doesn't describe why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the value of the index...

if you find the indexOf('IE') >= 0 hould be your line...